# ansible: how do I display the output from a task that using with_items?

Tags: ansible, sqlplus

Ansible newbie here
Hopefully there is a simple solution to my problem

I'm trying to run SQL across a number of Oracle databases on one node. I generate a list of databases from ps -ef and use with_items to pass the dbname values.

My question is how do I display the output from each database running the select statement?

```js
 tasks:

 

    - name: Exa check | find db instances

      become: yes

      become_user: oracle

      shell: |

         ps -ef|grep pmon|grep -v grep|grep -v ASM|awk '{ print $8 }'|cut -d '_' -f3

      register: instance_list_output

      changed_when: false

      run_once: true

 

    - shell: |

        export ORAENV_ASK=NO; export ORACLE_SID={{ item }}; export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/database/12.1.0.2/dbhome_1; source /usr/local/bin/oraenv; $ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus -s \"/ as sysdba\"<< EOSQL

        select * from v\$instance;

         EOSQL

      with_items:

      - "{{ instance_list_output.stdout_lines }}"

      register: sqloutput

      run_once: true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop below might work.

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item.stdout }}"
  loop: "{{ sqloutput.results }}"
```

If it does not take a look at the content of the variable and decide how to use it.

```
- debug: var=sqloutput
```

Comment: thanks Vladimir, the loop has given me the output but also exposed my problem. The second debug has provided me an invaluable insight to what my issue is.